# Error: "Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2" in SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2

Tags: json, react-native

I am facing this error when I am using JSON.parse. Below is the function. I am trying to get the values of the object in the item array for which I have to parse it first, but it is showing the error.

```
//function for get the data
 const viewUser = async () => {
    console.log('Loading');
     try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        const item = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
        const data=JSON.parse(item)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, "problem")
    }
  };
```

here is the function where I am setting the values. using math.random to get a unique key for every user.

```
const saveUser = async () => {
    var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    console.log('Saving');
    const userObject = {
      firstName: firstName,
      secondName: secondName,
      email: email,
    };
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      key,
      JSON.stringify(userObject)
    );
    console.log('saving done!');
    setFirstName('');
    setSecondName('');
    setEmail('');
  };
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

valid JSON string must have a double quote. wrap your key in a double quote using backticks

Answer (score 0):

The return values from `AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)` is not a stringified JSON but an array of tuples. To get the values you need to do the following:

```
 const viewUser = async () => {
    console.log('Loading');
     try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        const items = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
        // items is an array of tuples with first value as the key and second as the value
        let data = {}
        items.forEach(item => {
          data[item[0]] = item[1]
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, "problem")
    }
  };
```